# Can parameters be passed to a WPF user control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, prism

Can values or parameters be passed to a WPF user control? I am using MVVM pattern.

```
<local:SampleUserControlView Forecolor="{Binding ForeColor}"/>
```

where

> ForeColor is a property of Type Color or Brush in Viewmodel of the
>   window hosting SampleUserControl View.

By the way, should the property be of type Color or Brush?

Answer (score 9):

yes you can pass by using `dependency properties`. You can create dependency property in your usercontrol of type what you want to pass. Below is a small example which will show you how it works.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCustomProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("MyCustom", typeof(string), typeof(SampleUserControl));
public string MyCustom
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetValue(MyCustomProperty) as string;
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(MyCustomProperty, value);
    }
}
```

And `MyCustom` you can set from your parent VM, like

```
<local:SampleUserControlView MyCustom="{Binding MyCustomValue}"/>
```

Comment: It didn't work. I can see the value in xaml but the dependency property doesn't get the value. Its still null.

Comment: I suggested you an approach with the sample code. I'm using the same approach in order to pass data between Usercontrols. You can enhance this as per your need.

Comment: @user2330678 you are right , this will not be working