# Binding inside DataTemplate don't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatrigger

I am won to change View with DataTriger, but when bindings inside Triger don't work.
What i'm do wrong?
my style in resources

```
<Style x:Key="AgentPositionContentTemplateSelector" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate >
                <!--Agent name dont changed, Binding to "Agent" property dont work -->
                <TextBlock  Background="BlueViolet" Text="{Binding Agent}"></TextBlock> 
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <!--But this binding work perfect! DataTemplate changed!-->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Agent.PositionId, Converter={StaticResource IntToPositionDictionaryConverter} }"><!--Int to Enum-->
            <DataTrigger.Value>
                <enum:PositionDictionary>Merchandiser</enum:PositionDictionary>
            </DataTrigger.Value>

            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--And this binding don't work also!-->
                        <TextBlock Background="Aqua" Text="{Binding Agent}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

My View:

```
<ListBox Name="AgentsListBox" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionMode="Single"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Agent" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding CCRTeamRows}"><!--SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAgent}"-->

        </ListBox>
<!--This also work correct-->
<TextBlock  Text="{Binding Agent, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock  Text="{Binding Position, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Claster,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"></TextBlock>

<ContentControl Style="{DynamicResource AgentPositionContentTemplateSelector}" />
```

Please take me on right way.

Comment: What does "don't work" mean? What do you see, and what do you want to see instead? What is `Agent`?

Comment: Agent is property in my VM with overrided "ToString()" and it work correct on all places in my program.
I see nothing, and nothing is writed in output window..

Comment: Please provide enough code to replicate the issue. Also, see point 3 in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48099342/424129) for a way to diagnose binding issues. It’s a huge help.

Comment: Issue already solved by adding relative source.
Thank you, this realy useful information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the DataTemplates you'll need to use RelativeSource binding up to the ListBoxItem and then use Path=DataContext.Agent:

```
Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Agent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
```

Comment: Thanks,  I'm use ContentControl as Ancestor and this is solved 
Text="{Binding DataContext.Agent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}}